# Doubt about proof of compact connected surface with $K>0$ and $H/K$ constant must be sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> [image]

The solution is this:

> [image]

The theorems they mention at the end are:

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

I don't get what is happening here, I think the proof works like: Hilbert theorem's guarantees that whenever those conditions happen, then $p$ is a umbilic point but then we need this to be true for all points in $S$, right? If this is so, I'm not sure why all points in $S$ would be umbilic points. And then this guarantees that H and K are constant, and hence we can use the corollaries.

Also why is $H^2>0$ relevant?

Comment: If $k_1=k_2$ has both a maximum and a minimum at $p$, then $k_1=k_2$ must be constant. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought about that but how can we guarantee that it will work for the entire surface? It could be the case that there are only a few points where this happens, no?

Comment: We’re applying the theorem to the single point $p$. But $k_1$ and $k_2$ are globally defined. If $k_1\le k_2$ and they are equal where $k_1$ is (locally) smallest and $k_2$ is (locally) largest, then every point of this open set must be an umbilic. Now argue that the set of umbilic points is open (this argument) and closed (continuity).